# Qt crash when redrawing Widget

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a custom-built player which can "play" recoded media samples (sensor data with timestamps).

What I am trying to do is couple this player to an Qt UI. I have created a Widget and coupled the Player and the Widget through Signals and slots (Qt::DirectConnection).

The problem I'm experiencing is that the program crashes with an exception thrown. The moment when it crashes is completely random, and sometimes it may not crash. As far as I can tell, the problem lies in that the update in the widget part is not thread-safe. I have tried restricting access to it with a binary semaphore (immediately return if semaphore true, continue if not). The error still doesn't go away.

My question is: is the Qt Painter running on the same thread as the Widget updater? I suspect I'm calling the painter before the previous paint operation has finished, which is why it still crashes. I suspect the widget only somehow posts an event to the painter (non-blocking)..

What else could be the problem? Unfortunately, the code is too complex to paste here. However, I am attaching a screenshot of the crash.

Cheers,
Mihai

[image]

Comment: Are you forcing Qt::DirectConnection for signals and slots between different threads? If so, this is likely one possible reason for the random crashes.

Comment: If you want to paint on a widget, you should reimplement paint event. This is only good way for drawing. All GUI-related things will occur in a thread in which object was created. All GUI related things should be in main thread. And check that all objects are actually alive and you don't have memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. 
Merlin069, the wiring is as follows: 

connect( this, SIGNAL(updateStatusTree(tUInt64,tUInt64,int)),_widget,SLOT(updateStatusTree(tUInt64,tUInt64,int)), Qt::DirectConnection );

I have tried changing it to Qt::QueuedConnection. The update method on the Widget side never gets called anymore..

Comment: Is `this` an object that lives in a different thread from the main thread? If so, what is it doing with a `_widget` pointer?

Comment: "this" is the player object reference. It's connecting the current player object signal to the widget object slot.

Comment: And does the player object live in the main thread?

Comment: the Player object is independet from the UI Thread.

Comment: In that case having a pointer to a widget is quite dangerous. Also specifying connection type is unnecessary as the default is [`Qt::AutoConnection`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), which will check the thread affinity of the receiver during signal emission, and decide the connection type based on that. As to why the slot doesn't work when you use `Qt::QueuedConnection` it is hard to tell. I'm assuming nothing is blocking the event loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your precious feedback. I have managed to find the root cause for the problem. It was tied to the `Qt::DirectConnection`. As described in the API documentation, this will be executed:

> "in the emitter's thread, which is not necessarily the receiver's
>   thread."

In my case, the emitter is the Player and the receiver is the UI thread. Which means I'm manipulating elements in the UI outside of the UI Thread. This is the root cause.

I have changed the implementation to used `Qt::QueuedConnection` and now it runs smoothly.

As to why the original implementation with `Qt::QueuedConnection` did not work initially, I put a `bool status = connect()` which always returned `false`, meaning the connection failed. I changed the name of the signal method to be different from the name of the slot one (initially, they were the same), + I defaulted all the input parameters to standard types (`unsigned int` instead of `tUInt32`) and it worked. `connect()` now returns `true`. I suspect that somehow the `connect()` got confused as to the wiring..

Comment: Did you register your custom type with [`qRegisterMetaType`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType)? When you use slots with `Qt::QueuedConnection` connection type, you must register your custom type.